# FatalThrowableError in PDOConnection.php line 24 Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, connection

I have the message when trying login.
Everything was fine yesterdey.
I checked my connection to a database and checked MySQL server it's worked.

```
FatalThrowableError in PDOConnection.php line 24:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

in PDOConnection.php line 24
at Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php') in ClassLoader.php line 322
at ClassLoader->loadClass('Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection')
at spl_autoload_call('Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection')
at class_exists('Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection') in Connector.php line 115
at Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=fuckerbot', 'root', '****', array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in Connector.php line 56
at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=fuckerbot', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '3306', 'database' => 'fuckerbot', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '*****', 'charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'engine' => null, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, false)) in MySqlConnector.php line 24
at MySqlConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '3306', 'database' => 'fuckerbot', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '*****', 'charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'engine' => null, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 126
at ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
at call_user_func(object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 965
at Connection->getPdo() in Connection.php line 986
at Connection->getReadPdo() in Connection.php line 423
at Connection->getPdoForSelect(true) in Connection.php line 333
at Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(object(MySqlConnection), 'select * from `users` where `email` = ? limit 1', array('admin@admin.ru')) in Connection.php line 763
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `users` where `email` = ? limit 1', array('admin@admin.ru'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 726
at Connection->run('select * from `users` where `email` = ? limit 1', array('admin@admin.ru'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 351
at Connection->select('select * from `users` where `email` = ? limit 1', array('admin@admin.ru'), true) in Builder.php line 1648
at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1634
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 638
at Builder->getModels(array('*')) in Builder.php line 327
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 297
at Builder->first() in EloquentUserProvider.php line 104
at EloquentUserProvider->retrieveByCredentials(array('email' => 'admin@admin.ru', 'password' => '*****')) in SessionGuard.php line 353
at SessionGuard->attempt(array('email' => 'admin@admin.ru', 'password' => '*******'), false) in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 76
at LoginController->attemptLogin(object(Request)) in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 42
at LoginController->login(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LoginController), 'login'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('login', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(LoginController), 'login') in Route.php line 189
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 24
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

It's all stack trace from the error message. I not found and points from my code. One moment on the local system it's project work correctly. But a remote server has the error.

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: 7.2,  I switched to php7.0 bге problem still exists

Comment: @SergeyMakarenko you've given us the exception type and the stack trace, but what's the actual error message text?

Comment: @ADyson here is the error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE). If you need I can attach a screenshot.

Comment: No a screenshot is not necessary - errors are text, not pictures. But you could edit the question text to include the full error. And then next you need to show the code which threw the error, so we can help you to fix it. Sounds like it's probably a fairly simple syntax error, but without the exact code we can't give you an exact answer.

Comment: @ADyson I added all information about the error message. It's all that I have. It's message is in laravel.log and response html from server.

Comment: Like I said, we need the code as well. The error message tells you which code is causing the problem. If you have a difference in one server and another then first check the code is definitely identical in both, and then next check that you're using the same test data in each case. That will rule out any differences in data causing the issue. You need to try and narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening at [this line](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/bbd004c1e4c64287077e13e1bb0a68821d6bb703/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php#L24):

```
public function __construct($dsn, $user = null, $password = null, ?array $options = null)
```

Specifically at the question mark `?` before `array $options`.

This is a [new feature](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) that was introduced in PHP v7.1 called Nullable types.

You must be on version 7.1 or higher for this error to go away.

Comment: Thank you very much) I had installed two version php. Apache used 7.0 I changed it and my project is working.

Answer (score 0):

actually Laravel 5.3 requires a PHP version between 5.6.4 and 7.1.* and you've changed it, maybe you didn't activate the right extensions listed here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation after installing PHP 7.0 no?

Comment: I don't wanna upgrade PHP version for some reason, is there any other way for solving this issue?